# I am getting "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable" error in selenium 2

Tags: selenium-webdriver

While trying to launch Chrome browser, i am getting the above stated error. Chrome opens for a while, then it closes automatically.

Chrome version : **27**

chromedriver version : **chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0**

The log file contains:

```
[0612/150351:INFO:chromedriver_server.cc(76)] Handling request: /status 
[0612/150351:INFO:chromedriver_server.cc(81)] Done handling request: 200 {"sessionId":"","status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"alpha"},"os":{"arch":"x86","name":"Windows NT","version":"6.1"}}}
[0612/150351:INFO:chromedriver_server.cc(76)] Handling request: /session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platform":"ANY","browserName":"chrome","chromeOptions":{"args":[],"extensions":[]},"version":"","chrome.switches":[]}}
[0612/150351:INFO:chrome_launcher.cc(74)] Using chrome from C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
[0612/150414:INFO:chromedriver_server.cc(81)] Done handling request: 200 {"sessionId":"","status":101,"value":{"message":"chrome not reachable\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=0.8,platform=Windows NT 6.1 x86)"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the chrome driver form this link and check if it is working.

http://chromedriver.googlecode.com/files/chromedriver_win32_2.0.zip